# ¿Como puedo hacer para cargar la ruta de una imagen al sql server desde visual studio usando c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de Windows Forms en Visual Studio 2015, con una base de datos en SQL Server Management Studio 2013 y quiero poder agregar una imagen desde un form del proyecto y que me guarde la ruta de la misma en mi base de datos.

```
if (ValidarDatos())
        {
            if (imagen==null)
            {
                imagen = new Imagen();
            }
            string imagenNoDisponible = Application.StartupPath + "\\Imágenes\\" + "imagenNoDisponible.jpg";
            if (imagen.RutaImagen != null || imagen.RutaImagen != string.Empty)
            {
                archivoNombre = imagen.RutaImagen;
                string archivoNombreConRuta = Application.StartupPath + "\\Imágenes\\" + archivoNombre;
                if (File.Exists(archivoNombreConRuta))
                {
                    picImagenes.Image = Image.FromFile(@archivoNombreConRuta);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (File.Exists(imagenNoDisponible))
                        picImagenes.Image = Image.FromFile(@imagenNoDisponible);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(imagenNoDisponible))
                    picImagenes.Image = Image.FromFile(@imagenNoDisponible);
            }
            if (!Editar)
            {
                try
                {
                    ImagenBD.Agregar(imagen);
                    MessageBox.Show("Imagen agregada", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea agregar otra Imagen?", "Continuar",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        InicializarControles();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ignacion, has intentado algo?

Comment: Hola, mira por favor [ask]. Lo que queres hacer es guardar un string en la base de datos? que intentaste hasta ahora? donde encontraste algun problema?

Comment: Hola, si eso es lo que quiero hacer, hasta ahora en mi proyecto puedo seleccionar una imagen de mi pc y verla en un pictureBox, pero parece que solo me muestra la imagen y no me trae la ruta. Por eso cuando intento guardarla en mi base, la columna de la ruta de la imagen me aparece en blanco

Comment: si la estas cargando en un picturebox, sabes la ruta (pq se la dices a el, para que la cargue), o por lo menos la estas pasando a algun tipo de objeto que la transforme. Muestra el codigo que llevas y como tratas de pasar la info a la BD para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Perfecto, acabo de subir en la consulta, el código del botón guardar imagen del form, creo que ahí esta el error, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ok, tu ruta es archivoNombreConRuta , entonces, la estas mandando en algun lado a la base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Si únicamente quieres obtener la ruta en la que se encuentra la imagen, lo puedes hacer cuando la insertas en el `PictureBox`, mira el siguiente código:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName); //La propiedad FileName de un openFileDialog guarda la ruta donde se almacena el archivo seleccionado. 
        }
```

El formato que tiene la ruta obtenida mediante la propiedad `Filename` es:

"C:\\New folder\\imagen.jpg"

Una vez obtenida la ruta la almacenas como un `string`

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de una base, cuando armas una ruta deberias usar

```
string imagenNoDisponible = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Imágenes\imagenNoDisponible.jpg");
```

de esta forma haces mas seguro la creacion de la ruta

---

Si la db que usas es `Sql Server` deberia estar en un servidor de base de datos, o sea separado a la aplicacion cliente que ejecuta en una pc, por lo tanto la copia de la imagen seleccionada deberia realizarse a una carpeta compartida, esta carpeta podrias definirla por configuracion por si llegara a cambiar no tienes que recompilar.

Ahora bien, cuando seleccionas un archivo esta claro que al asignarlo a un `PictureBox` este no retorna la ruta, sino que deberas consevar en una variable separada, o si lo prefieres en la propiedad `Tag` del control de imagen

```
picImagenes.Tag = imagenNoDisponible;
```

en caso de necesitar recuperar la ruta podras hacerlo sin problemas y proceder a la copia

```
string rutaImagen = picImagenes.Tag.ToString();
File.Copy(rutaImagen, rutaDestino);
```

pero remarco que la db no deberia estar en la misma pc que la aplicacion

en la base de datos solo persistiras el nombre de la image, para eso utilizas

```
string nombreImagen = Path.GetFileName(rutaImagen);
```

eso es lo que registras en la tabla, ya que para recuperarlo armas la ruta completa uniendo la carpeta que defines por configuracion donde estaran als imagenes + el nombre de la imagen que obtienes del campo en la tabla